# Running in an error using BigInteger class

Tags: java, biginteger, jgrasp

I'm currently in the process of doing an assignment for one of my class using the BigInteger class. The problem I'm running into is with the .pow method. its giving me this error 
BigNumberExample1.java:25: error: incompatible types: BigInteger cannot be converted to int
      BigInteger input4 = (a.pow(b).mod(n));

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
class BigNumberExample1{

   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      try 
      {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.println("Enter number a");
      String A = in.readLine();
      System.out.println("Enter number b");
      String B = in.readLine();

      BigInteger a = new BigInteger(A);
      BigInteger b = new BigInteger(B);
      BigInteger input1 = (a.xor(b));
      BigInteger input2 = (a.or(b));
      BigInteger input3 = (a.or(b).and(a));    
      System.out.println("Enter number n");
      String N = in.readLine();
      BigInteger n = new BigInteger(N);
      BigInteger input4 = (a.pow(b).mod(n));
      BigInteger input5 = (a.shiftRight(5));
      BigInteger input6 = (b.shiftLeft(7));
      System.out.println(input1);
      System.out.println(input2);
      System.out.println(input3);
      System.out.println(input4);
      System.out.println(input5);
      System.out.println(input6);
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Comment: there is another method called modPow, have you considered using it instead of that code? also note that pow() gets int as argument not BigInteger

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow(int)), it takes an int value in pow():

```
pow(int exponent)
```

so do:

```
a.pow(b.intValue()).mod(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`BigInteger.pow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29) takes an `int` and not a `BigInteger`. Since `b` is a `BigInteger` you could do something like:

```
BigInteger input4 = a.pow(b.intValue()).mod(n);
```

but that will break if `b` is bigger than an `int`.  Your best bet is to use [`BigInteger.modPow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) instead since that takes 2 `BigIntegers`. Then you end up with:

```
BigInteger input4 = a.modPow(b, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks to me like a.pow(b) is expecting 'b' to be an integer, not a big int

Try BigInteger input4 = (a.pow(b.intValue()).mod(n));